# Woocommerce hook - remove category title from product category pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove category title from woo-commerce product category pages.

Any hook for removing category title same as product title hook? I have googled and tried so many things for it but didn't found right solution. Found hook for removing product title.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
```

Need a hook same like above for removing category title.

**Is any hook for category title?**

Answer (score 2):

The Function `woocommerce_template_loop_category_title()` is responsible to return the title of category on shop or category page in woocommerce You can [see here for more details](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title/)

**using hook 1st method**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10, 2 );
```

**using css 2nd method**

```
function remove_cat_title_from_cat_or_shop_page($category){
    if ( is_product_category() || is_shop() ) {
        echo"<style>";
        echo".woocommerce ul.products li.product .woocommerce-loop-category__title{display:none!important;}";
        echo"</style>";
    } 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'remove_cat_title_from_cat_or_shop_page');
```

result 
[image]

Comment: Not working! This hook is for page title, I want to remove "category title" from product category page.

Comment: You mean you want to remove the word "Category:" ? or want to remove its name?

Comment: want to remove its name

Comment: @AbhaRana I have updated my answer. Here is the (reference link)[http://hookr.io/functions/woocommerce_template_loop_category_title/]

Comment: Thanks for your time. But still its not working. I have added hook in my child theme's function.php file

Comment: I see but works perfect in my theme. Maybe its your theme issue so you can try 2nd method I have added on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Theme is overriding the hook

```
woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title
```

**woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title** hook is responsible to return the title. In my case also this was an issue.