# woocommerce category and subcategory title hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to modify the default title of a category and relative subcategory of woocommerce. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568385/woocommerce-hook-remove-category-title-from-product-category-pages), but this will only remove the title from the category.

Using the inspector I was able to find this css class `.woocommerce-loop-category__title` but I'm not able to understand what hook is responsable to render the title of the categories and subcategories.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code

```
function theme_woocommerce_loop_category_title()
  {
    if( is_product_category() ):
    ?>
      <h2 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php
    endif;
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 'theme_woocommerce_loop_category_title', 10 );

  remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title
```

This hook is responsible for category title so if you want to update your category title then you may do it like this

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_category_title_override( $category ) { ?>
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">
        <?php
        echo esc_html( $category->name ); //Update your title which you want to update here
        if ( $category->count > 0 ) {
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . esc_html( $category->count ) . ')</mark>', $category );
        } ?>
        </h2><?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title_override', 10 );
```

Comment: I've found it inside the `wc_template_functions` file. I'm a bit confused with some hooks, I'm not experienced with woocommerce customization. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's fine, you're welcome! let me know if you need any further help, hope this helps for your needs!